# finding max width of blob

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, vb6

I'm trying to find the maximum width of the blob by counting the number of white pixels of each line in the blob I wrote the code, however, it never stops. how it can be fixed?

```
For y = 0 To bmp.ScaleHeight - 1
    sum = 0
    For x = 0 To bmp.ScaleWidth - 1
        pixel1 = bmp.Point(x, y)
        If pixel1 = vbWhite Then
            sum = sum + 1
            If bmp.Point(x + 1, y) = vbBlack Then
                If sum > max Then
                    Lmax = sum
                    y1 = y
                    x2 = x
                    x1 = x2 - sum
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next y
```

Comment: Are you sure that it never stops? Or did you just get tired of waiting for it to stop? The loop *should* terminate, although it's probably going to be pretty slow on large images.

Comment: I agree with [Jim Mischel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel), the x & y vars don't get changed except by the for loops, so it will end at one point.

Put some Debug.Print statements for x and y vars so you get a sense of how the code progresses, and how long you should wait.

Comment: I don't agree. Even for 1000x1000 images, the loop should terminate in a fraction of a second. Isn't by accident the width and/or height of the image 0? That would cause a long run.

Comment: Is ScaleHeight in pixels? If it is in twips it could make the result a bit meaningless. Have you stepped it through in the debugger? In my experience Point is very slow.